# How can I manipulate strings in a slice of a pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `MultiIndex` like this:

```
                                 metric
sensor  variable   side  
foo        Speed   Left      Left speed
                  Right     Right speed
bar        Speed   Left      Left_Speed
                  Right     Right_Speed
baz        Speed   Left           speed
foo      Support   Left    Left support
                  Right   Right support
bar      Support   Left    Left_support
                  Right   Right_support
baz      Support   Left         support
```

I'm trying to apply a string mapping to a slice of this dataframe:

```
df.loc['baz',:,'Left'].metric.map(lambda s: "Left_" + s)
```

How can I apply this map to just the `baz-Left` rows, and get back the resulting `DataFrame`?

```
                                 metric
sensor  variable   side  
foo        Speed   Left      Left speed
                  Right     Right speed
bar        Speed   Left      Left_Speed
                  Right     Right_Speed
baz        Speed   Left      Left_speed
foo      Support   Left    Left support
                  Right   Right support
bar      Support   Left    Left_support
                  Right   Right_support
baz      Support   Left    Left_support
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following method, but i think/hope there must be a more elegant way to achieve that:

```
In [101]: index_saved = df.index
```

Let's sort index in order to get rid of `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (3), lexsort depth (0)'` error:

```
In [102]: df = df.sort_index()

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
                              metric
sensor variable side
bar    Speed    Left      Left_Speed
                Right    Right_Speed
       Support  Left    Left_support
                Right  Right_support
baz    Speed    Left           speed
       Support  Left         support
foo    Speed    Left      Left speed
                Right    Right speed
       Support  Left    Left support
                Right  Right support

In [119]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['baz', :, 'Left'], 'metric'] = \
     ...:     'AAA__' + df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['baz', :, 'Left'], 'metric']

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
                              metric
sensor variable side
bar    Speed    Left      Left_Speed
                Right    Right_Speed
       Support  Left    Left_support
                Right  Right_support
baz    Speed    Left      AAA__speed
       Support  Left    AAA__support
foo    Speed    Left      Left speed
                Right    Right speed
       Support  Left    Left support
                Right  Right support
```

set back old (saved) index:

```
In [121]: df = df.reindex(index_saved)

In [122]: df
Out[122]:
                              metric
sensor variable side
foo    Speed    Left      Left speed
                Right    Right speed
bar    Speed    Left      Left_Speed
                Right    Right_Speed
baz    Speed    Left      AAA__speed
foo    Support  Left    Left support
                Right  Right support
bar    Support  Left    Left_support
                Right  Right_support
baz    Support  Left    AAA__support
```

Comment: My data is actually available already separated by `sensor`.. I guess it'd be simpler to grab this one separately, do my manipulating, then `merge` the results.  Still curious if there's a nice way to do this though!